# Database Design: force a child table to populate with predefined data when the parent record is created

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, constraints

I hope this isn't going to be too broad a question or too subjective (and please correct me if it is) but what are the best practices or most ideal way of populating the rows of a child table with data that MUST exist when a parent record is created?

I have come across something like this [Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vafz.png)
 in the past (This is not a real database design, this is just something i threw together in MySQL workbench to give you the general idea. i know there are errors in it)

When a test is applied to a 'sample' (i.e, a record is added to the 'SampleTest' table) all of the 'components' that comprise that test need to be added to the 'SampleResult' table, almost as if the 'test' and 'component' tables contain a template for the 'SampleTest' and 'SampleResult' tables.

What is the best way to ensure that the 'SampleResult' table gets populated with all the records it needs when a test is applied to a sample?

Example data:

The `Test` table contains a test called `Metals`.

The `Metals` test is made up of several `Component` records; `Arsenic`, `Iron`, `Aluminium`, etc...

The `Metals` test is added to a sample by adding a record to the `SampleTest` Table.

At that point the `SampleResult` Table needs to have records linking to the three components; `Arsenic`, `Iron` and `Aluminium`.

Should this be dealt with by the database itself or is this a front-end issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two options are:

1. Implement in the database in the form of a [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html), where the trigger would look something like this:

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER ins_test_components 
       AFTER INSERT ON SampleTest
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO SampleResult (component_id, ...)
       SELECT components.id, ...
       FROM Components, Test
       WHERE Test.id = NEW.Test_id
   END
   ```

   The trigger above will insert all the components of the Test who's `id` is in the `NEW` row inserted into the SampleTest.

   Here's a [tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx) on triggers.
2. Implement this within in the Application, but make sure it is framed within a transaction so that if something goes wrong the whole thing will be aborted and the database will remain in a consistent state. This is definitely not a front-end issue, since you need to add things in the database table as a side-effect of another `INSERT`.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much. the main thing i was wondering was about the data/application separation; whether this situation is considered part of the data structure or part of the work-flow. Or perhaps in the grey-area between the two.

Comment: The end goal is to have the database in a consistent state at any point in time regardless of the errors that may occur during execution. If any of the two methods achieve then they are both good. I think the decision lies on where is this code, easier to maintain? If you make changes to this process is it straight forward to change this trigger? Is it straight forward to change the application logic?